# Show Only Icons in Bootstrap 4 Dropdown Menu with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I want to create a **Web Icon Font Dropdown Menu** that shows the corresponding text next to the Flag Icons **ONLY** when the menu is opened.

When a selection is made and the menu is closed, I want to see **ONLY** the Active Flag Icon without the text.

The webpage should load with one of the flags Active by default ex: Greece

[image: By default it should be selected with one of the options like Greece]
[image: When you click on it, it should tell you more about the country]

This is my JQuery code, I think the problems lies in **this(TEXT)** But I'm sure someone can fix this code, or maybe even offer a better solution since I'm sure Bootstrap 4 might have other options using the active state add class/remove class with jQuery.

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>' + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
  $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
});
```

**My HTML(Using Bootstrap 4)**

```
<nav class="p-0 navbar navbar-expand fixed-top bg-white fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="container-fluid navbar-nav js-signin-modal-trigger justify-content-end list-unstyled" id="navbar2SupportedContent">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="bg-light btn btn-default dropdown-toggle mx-0" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gr"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu text-left" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="action"><span class="ml-2 label label-default"><span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gr"></span>Greece</span> </a> </li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="another action"><span class="ml-2 flag-icon flag-icon-fr"></span> <span>France</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="something else here"><span class="ml-2 flag-icon flag-icon-us"></span> <span>United States</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-value="separated link"><span class="ml-2 flag-icon flag-icon-es"></span><span> España</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-signin="login" class="Loginbtn font-weight-bold btn navbar-btn px-md-4 px-sm-2 px-xs-1">Log in</a></li>                
            <li><a href="#" data-signin="signup" class="signupbtn text-white font-weight-bold btn navbar-btn px-md-4 px-sm-2 px-xs-1 ml-md-2 ml-sm-1 btn-secondary">Sign up</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is a nice little Fiddle to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/stvu5ckj/1/

My motivation behind this code is the website www.nextdoor.com If I can create something exactly like that it will be PERFECT!

[image: Next Door - Great Sample of what I want]

Answer (score -1):

Hi i would suggest that you must load a json file with the iso names of all countrys then in your each match the code with the boostrap code and you will get the country name here is the json btw [Json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/country-codes)

Hope it Helps